# PDO не удаляются данные из бд

Tags: mysql

есть такой запрос    
try{
    $db->exec("DELETE FROM `cat` WRERE `id`=5");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'error';
    exit;
}
Проблема в том , что данные не удаляются , и исключение не срабатывает  исключение , в чём может быть проблема ?
Если написать   
echo $db->errorCode();
То выводит 42000

Comment: я надеюсь, там WHERE, а не WRERE.
Вопрос два:)
а запрос вида select * from cat where id=5 возвращает хотя бы одну запись? может нет что и удалять?

Comment: Блин , вот я слепой . Тогда почему же исключение не срабатывало ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить вот этой [таблице](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jenut/ch08_06.htm), то 42000 - неверный синтаксис. Что собственно видно по коду (WRERE вместо WHERE). Почему же не срабатывает исключение? Есть подозрение, что не хватает кусочка кода. Посмотрите на пример в конце этой [странцы](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php). Подозреваю, что по умолчанию выставлено молчаливый режим. Смените его методом $db->setAttribute